# How to keep a hidden window alive in background in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I keep a window alive when it is hidden, I'm trying this code out ..

Win1 : Contains Current time and date. ON Button Click the win2 window opens and win1 Hides.

Win2 : In win2 window i have passed the value of the win1 textbox using property.

But in win2 the time is not getting updated .. this means the win1 is not alive anymore

Any suggestions?

```
{
    public win1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer(new TimeSpan(0,0,1), DispatcherPriority.Normal, delegate
        {
            this.textb.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt");
        }, this.Dispatcher);
    }

    private void Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void but_send_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        win2 w2 = new win2();
        w2.passval = textb.Text;
        this.Hide();
        w2.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

and this is my second window  win2.xaml.cs

```
{
    private string nm;

    public string passval
    {
        get { return nm; }
        set { nm = value;}
    }     

    public win2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        lbl1.Content = "Time " + nm;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are updating Win1's `TextBox`. The following line copies the string located in `textb.Text` into `w2.passval`:

```
w2.passval = textb.Text;
```

But that's it: further updates to `textb.Text` has no effect on the `w2.passval` property.

Furthermore, keeping a reference to `w2` in  `Win1` and directly updating `w2.passval` from your delegate, would also not update the contents of lbl1 since your are only updating its value  when the Grid is loaded. Therefore you'll need to:

1. Update `w2.passval` from the delegate in `Win1`. For instance:

   ```
   public win1()         
   {
       InitializeComponent();

       DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer(new TimeSpan(0,0,1), DispatcherPriority.Normal, delegate
       {
           this.textb.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt");
           if (_w2 != null)
               _w2.passval = textb.Text;
       }, this.Dispatcher);
   }

   private win2 _w2 = null; // Reference to your Win2

   private void but_send_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       _w2 = new win2();
       _w2.passval = textb.Text;
       this.Hide();
       w2.ShowDialog();
   }
   ```
2. Update the `Label` in `Win2`. For instance:

   ```
   private string nm;

   public string passval
   {
       get { return nm; }
       set { 
           nm = value; 
           // This should rather be done somewhere else, not in the setter
           lbl1.Content = "Time " + nm; 
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time Jnovo ... i got it now it worked :) thumps up